# Windows cannot write to subdirectories of home directory shared with Samba

Tags: samba

I'm sharing my homes directories in a VMWare Ubuntu guest to a Windows 7 host. I can write to the `/home/user` directory with no problem but when I drill down into sub-directories, Windows tells me I do not have permission to perform this action.

Here are the settings I changed:

```
[homes]
  comment = Home Directories
  browseable = yes
  writable = yes
  create mask = 0777
  directory mask = 0777
  guest ok = yes
  valid users = %s
```

I'm not yet proficient with Linux so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Try 0664 on create mask and 0775 on directories. (0777 might be disabled in samba).

Comment: No change. Can still write to home/user directory but not home/user/subdirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the following in the configuration:

**From:**

```
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

**To:**

```
create mask = 1777
directory mask = 1777
```

Finally restart the sharing service.

Comment: No change. Can still write to home/user but not home/user/subdirectory. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: From terminal try the following: `chod -R 1777 /home/your_user_name_here`

Comment: This worked but I was concerned about doing something like this from a security point of view -- not a big deal since it's a VM. I see the 1 alleviates that. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that Samba will manage access to the share. 1 is a sticky bit that guaranties that every child file will have the same permissions.